# Откуда пошло выражение "нажить себе геморрой"?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

"Нажить себе геморрой" — значит столкнуться с проблемами, которых можно было избежать. Откуда оно появилось?

Answer (score 1):

Болезнь геморрой наживают себе люди, которые не следят за здоровьем, не пытаются предотвратить появление этой неприятности. В переносном смысле значение примерно то же самое: геморроем называют именно  те проблемы, которых можно было бы избежать, если что–то предпринимать для их решения , а  не пускать все на самотёк.
Это означает, что каждому человеку надо задуматься над  возможностью возникновения проблемы, в случае необходимости сделать всё возможное,  чтобы предотвратить её появление, пересмотреть свой образ жизни. Не случайно, именно «геморроем» называют появление серьезной проблемы в жизни или на работе.
Кроме того, вспомните, пожалуйста, отношение разных народов к "заветному" месту  на теле человека. Если у русских "спасите наши души", то у американцев "спасаем наши зад...цы" Можно вспомнить и устойчивое выражение  - найти себе приключение на пятую точку, (опять фигурирует та же самая часть тела).

Answer (score 1):

[Из Википедии:](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9)

> Геморро́й (от др.-греч. αἷμα — «кровь» и ῥοῦς (< ῥόος) — «течение»);
>   мед. устар. и обл. почечу́й) — заболевание, связанное с тромбозом,
>   воспалением, патологическим расширением и извитостью геморроидальных
>   вен, образующих узлы вокруг прямой кишки.

В русской культуре проблемы принято ассоциировать ровно с той частью тела, где геморрой возникает. Аналогично выражению "найти приключений на свою задницу".

Answer (score 0):

Это шуточная вариация выражения "нажить головную боль".Замена вполне очевидная,по принципу "наоборот",и применяется во всех подобных контекстах:"Зачем тебе этот геморрой?" и т.п.Теперь уже стала устойчивой,как когда-то "легкая нога" сменила "легкую руку".

Comment: «Когда-то "легкая нога" сменила "легкую руку"»? === Когда же и зачем? И ещё: с каких пор и зачем фразы лепятся вплотную друг к другу?

Comment: Когда - точно не скажу,но на моей памяти.Все же шибко остроумные,и "легкая рука" никто уже не говорит,только "легкая нога".По моим наблюдениям,конечно.А пробелы после запятых и точек нужны,только если текст подлежит дальнейшей верстке,а так они просто ни к чему,без них все читается точно так же.

Comment: Интересное соображение про «просто ни к чему». Особенно здесь, где основная тема — письменность и её правила . Может быть, ещё что-то есть по части напрасной траты энергии на ненужные знаки?

Comment: Письменность,вы уверены? Мне уже попался вопрос о том,как произносить удвоенные согласные.К письменности он никакого отношения не имеет.Если вы против таких вопросов,обращайтесь к администрации.Я и сам подумываю обратиться к ней - по поводу флуда и троллинга в исполнении не то одного собеседника,не то одной собеседницы.

Comment: Хорошая идея — обходится одной буквой в случае удвоенной. А ещё можно попробовать не писать первую букву, если в предыдущем слове последняя буква такая же. Читается-то точно также.

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос топикстартера: "Откуда пошло?"

Comment: Мне очень понравилось "без них все читается точно так же". Надо будет запомнить.  А ещё "не то одного собеседника, не то одной собеседницы". А Вы, IAQ, попробуйте обращаться "ОНО"!  Вариант?Но, если серьёзно, варианта  "лёгкая нога" не слышала ни разу. Может, я не в тех кругах вращаюсь?